# Svelte Check if slot is empty while there's a fallback

Tags: svelte

My component defines a slot with a fallback, that means if the parent does not pass a content in for that specific slot, the fallback is rendered.
In addition, if the parent set an empty content for this slot, the slot is not display.

Suppose I want to render some other content whether the slot has been set as empty.

The doc says if the slot explicitly passes in an empty named slot will add that slot's name to $$slots properties. (which is contradictory with this part from the tutorial though : https://svelte.dev/tutorial/optional-slots).

```js
// MyComp.svelte
<div class="component">
   <slot name="foo">
    <div class="fallback-content"/>
   </slot>
  {#if $$slots.foo}
    <div class="other-content">Bar</div>
  {/if}
</div>
```

```
<MyComp>
   <div slot="foo"/> // I don't want ".other-content" to be displayed
</MyComp>
```

How can I know when a slot has been explicity define as empty in the parent?

Comment: *"..has been explicity define as empty in the parent"* What do you mean by this? Maybe you could add some code of what you do at the moment and what you would like to achieve

Comment: Added some code

Answer (score 1):

You already passed a div in the slot in your code:

```
<div slot="foo"/>
```

when you need to pass an empty fragment like this:

```
<svelte:fragment slot="foo"/>
```

Now the slot will be seen as empty and the fallback will work correctly.